# Promoting Ads of New Proposal

Tags: support

I have seen some ads on several SE communities about new proposal and beta sites. It can attract users to sites but thinking who does it.

**Do SE moderators  control the ads or they work automatically or I can ask for it?**

Answer (score 2):

Deciding on which ads to use seems  to be a yearly event held on each site's meta. For example, [here's](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1858/community-promotion-ads-2014) this year's discussion on Judaism.SE.

People post their image recommendations, and they get voted on.

Comment: You mean I will have to open discussion on related community site for a propose.

Comment: No, the SE team posts a question, and people post their suggestions, in a very rigid format.

Comment: So you mean specific community's team post question.

Comment: No, it's an SE employee.

Comment: So what do I do to get a proposal promoted?

Comment: When they are looking for ads, post on the topic. It seems like they do it every December.